# How would you create a cd material in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I know you can use the anisotropic BSDF shader to create the blurred effect but how would you make the weirdly reflected colours you get when you hold a CD to a light.

Here's an image example I found on Google Images:[image]

I want it so that you could create the colours without just using an image texture of a CD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the fake iridescence effect I achieved. Try to experiment with *Mapping* and *Anisotropic* nodes settings.
[image]
[image]

Here's an animated gif *(click on a picture below to see a larger version)*.
[image]