# How can I make a holographic material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm talking about those holographic designs you sometimes see on stickers and foil, not free floating holograms. [Examples here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=holographic%20stickers&rlz=1C1AVNC_enNL599NL599&espv=2&biw=1463&bih=751&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CD8QsARqFQoTCKaQ0tvXiMgCFUZGFAod51IGbA).

I also want this to change colors as real ones do when you rotate them.

I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fo03-ENBaw) that shows it's possible, but it doesn't list a method.

It's similar to iridescence, [but not the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_hologram). I don't see a clear path from the linked iridescence example to what I want.

Comment: related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/how-would-you-create-a-cd-material-in-cycles

Comment: That's close, but I wouldn't know hot to get from that to what you see on those stickers

Comment: Use textures to control the mixing of different shaders

Comment: I appeal to not close this question as this requires the separate solution. Hologram material behave slighty different from the iridescence material in my opinion.

Comment: @Gonzou holographic material is exactly iridescence material, just that each shape has different angle of iridescence.

Comment: I'm sorely disappointed in StackExchange (modding), as I don't see a clear path from iridescence to what I want. It's like marking a question duplicate because it uses the extrude function which has been covered elsewhere.

Comment: @David Can you explain *how* it is different from iridescence? As someone who voted for this to be a duplicate I don't personally understand the difference. But if you can explain how it is different, then both myself and others would be more likely to be convinced the question needs to be re-opened.

Comment: I'm not an expert so I can't comment too much on the physics. Luckily I found people on Blender Artists working on it. As you can see the technique is much more complex than show in the linked duplicate.

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?340095-A-complex-approach-Iridescence-in-cycles/page3

Comment: @cybrbeast That link described specifically irridescence as far as I can see - but you're saying that "holograms" are different to that. Please edit your quest to be more specific about what it is you require. I realise that this is an old question but without more specific information it will never be answered.