# How can I make oily material like Nyx Assassin?

Tags: materials, shaders

One of the characters of the Dota2 that Is called [Nyx Assassin](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Nyx_Assassin) has an interesting material effect If you look In below gif at the body and feet you can see this effect.It looks like [poily/polluted water](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/rendering-oily-polluted-water).I like to know how can I make something like this In blender:

[image: Nyx assassin]

I downloaded the [Model and texture files](http://www.dota2.com/workshop/requirements/nyx_assassin) and tried to Implement it but I couldn't do it.

[image: Nyx Assassin]

After reviewing the textures , I found a texture as specular wrap It seems that this texture has been used for this effect.I used this texture as specular but not work , I think special shader used to make this effect.

[image: specular wrap]

Comment: That is called [iridescence](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles) also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50961/how-to-create-iridescent-glossy-tile-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/how-would-you-create-a-cd-material-in-cycles

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks how can I use specular wrap texture as Color Ramp? I need extracting Color Ramp from it.