# Is there any way to replicate "Aura Glow" reflective dispersion/iridescence glass effect in Cycles?

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm currently working on a model for Samsung Galaxy Note10+, with one of the colors used on the phone is "Aura Glow" that is a very reflective glass that reflects  light (a la CD/DVDs):

[image: A GIF demonstrating the "Aura Glow" color]

However, I couldn't get the effect working as intended in Cycles, Blender 2.90.

- Using the [RGB Glass BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40836/124038) method shows the result correctly in Material Preview/Eevee, but appears transparent in Cycles render (note that the front of the phone appears as "see through"). Mixing with Principled BSDF didn't help much.
  [image: RGB Glass BSDF in Eevee]

[image: RGB Glass BSDF in Cycles]

[image: RGB Glass BSDF+Principled BSDF in Cycles]

- Using [Anisotropic rainbow ramp](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35817/124038) method only gives out a solid red finish.
  [image: Anisotropic rainbow ramp]

I can't seem to find any other method that actually reflects like what I intended to, so I'd like anyone to help me on giving a reflective glass like that GIF above.

Comment: Apart from the answer @Luciano has given: check your node settings. The node setup you're linking to uses _Normal_ in the _Mapping_ nodes, not _Point_. Although when I try it the difference is not as extreme as in your screenshot, but the results are definitely not the same when you're using _Point_.

Comment: @Luciano that works, but only in BI render, which is gone with the game engine.

Comment: Did you try using a metallic shader instead of glass?

Comment: @Luciano I've tested the second answer of the thread linked (which is a bit complicated lol) and after I tweaked a bit, it now look exactly as I wanted! Should I update this to include the node setup I used?

Comment: @logoffon no, don’t update the question, but post it as a new answer. You can answer your own questions on this site for other users to know 

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard If you're referring to using PBSDF with metallic set to max and different IOR settings in place of glass in first method, it [didn't work](https://i.imgur.com/0fRzfik.png).

Comment: No, I mean just using metallic as opposed to glass, but thinking about that longer I can see the obvious problem  Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1728/124038) actually do work, but for my use, a bit of tweaking has to be done to make it look like the actual phone:

[image: node setup]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just one question, those four values on the left side, are you going to change them? Because they are not connected to group node inputs which means you cannot change them from outside the group. If they stay like they are, I have a much much easier node setup for you because there are a lot of redundancies... (for example, the _Dot Product_ goes into _Arcsin_ > _Sin_, which is nonsense... sin(arcsin(x)) = x.)

Comment: What a pity, the question is closed. But to make your node setup easier: Delete all four _Value_ nodes. Enter the _Strength_ 0.5 directly into the _Bump_ node. Then delete all _Math_ nodes after the _Dot Product_ except for the last _Modulo_ node. Now add a _Math_ node set to _Multiply Add_. Plug the _Dot Product_ in the top _Value_ socket, enter 2 into the _Multiplier_ input and 0.5 into the _Addend_ input. Plug the result in the top value of the _Modulo_ node, leave the bottom value at 1. That's all, you just need two nodes between _Dot Product_ and _Color Ramp_.

Comment: I've already changed them to suit my need, so I don't really need to alter those again. But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Oh, and for varying the colors a little you can change the _Addend_ value somewhere between 0.0 and 1.0, changing the _Multiplier_ brings variation too, but going below 1 makes the colors less "rainbowy" and more monochrome.