# Duo-Chrome Style Shaders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, pbr

I've been attempting to create a material that mimics the effect you see in some cosmetics that are labeled "duo chrome" or "color changing", where you would have one base color that reflects a different color based on lighting conditions.
Some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried mimicking this effect using layer weight or Fresnel, but I'm not really satisfied with the results:

[image]

Here is my node setup:
[image]

I'm trying to get both the color shifting effect in the base color and the highlight color, but I'm kind of stumped. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50961/how-to-create-iridescent-glossy-tile-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99251/cycles-material-a-kind-of-glitter https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/how-would-you-create-a-cd-material-in-cycles/35817#35817